# Time interval between location updates, iphone

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager, frequency

I have a CLLocation Manager called "myLocation"

```
myLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    myLocation.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation ;
        myLocation.delegate=self;
[myLocation startUpdatingLocation];
```

I need to know time interval between location updates. I am using timestamp to find when new location was found as follows in didUpdateToLocation method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSTimeInterval locationAge = abs([oldLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow]);

    NSString *timeinNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationAge];

    NSLog(@"Location Age is %@", timeinNSString);
}
```

But NSlog always prints 0. any Idea what I am missing here? 
Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`abs()` doesn't work with floating point numbers. Use `fabs()` instead. In the future, use breakpoints and step through your code in the debugger to check where it actually fails.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. using fabs() solves the problem. code doesn't fail if abs() is used though.

Comment: @lxt: wrong! `@"%d"` is used for integers, equivalent to `@"%i"`. `@"%f"` is the correct format specifiers for both floats and doubles.

Comment: You are indeed correct. Serves me right for posting whilst holed up in bed sick!